# SOAP webservice call to a method using jquery ajax that sends 2 parameters, how to catch the responses in a loop

Tags: ajax, soap

I have a SOAP webservice created in c# (hosted on localhost) called soapService.aspx . It has a method called displayClass(String id, String theDate)
it returns. This returns following json

```
[{"lesson_id":2,"customer_id":4,"instructor_id":8,"dance_style_id":2,"hourly_rate":20,"lesson_time":"Afternoon","lesson_date":"03/12/2015","start_time":"11:22","end_time":"14:22 ","notes":"test test","payment_status":0,"status":0,"lesson_slot":null,"duration":3},{"lesson_id":3,"customer_id":4,"instructor_id":8,"dance_style_id":2,"hourly_rate":20,"lesson_time":"Afternoon","lesson_date":"03/12/2015","start_time":null,"end_time":null,"notes":null,"payment_status":0,"status":0,"lesson_slot":null,"duration":3},{"lesson_id":4,"customer_id":4,"instructor_id":8,"dance_style_id":2,"hourly_rate":20,"lesson_time":"Afternoon","lesson_date":"03/12/2015","start_time":null,"end_time":null,"notes":null,"payment_status":0,"status":0,"lesson_slot":null,"duration":3}]
```

I found this using web service invoke method given on the web service description page.

I want to catch the response using ajax.

So far I wrote this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function displayClass() {
        var instructorInputID = $('#instructorIdText').val();
        var instructorInputDate = $('#instructordateText').val();
        //send this id to web service

        $.ajax({

            url: "http://localhost/soapService.asmx/displayClasses",
            type: POST,
            dataType:"json",
            data:instructorInput,
            contentType:"application/json; charset:utf-8",

            success:function(msg){

                //process the msg

            }


        });

    }

});
```

1) How do I invoke the web service method by passing parameters 
2) How do i display all these json data in a table? Please help

Edit : Tried to post

```
 data: "{'id': '" + instructorInputID + "','theDate': '" + instructorInputDate + "'}",
```

THis is the response I get from console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:18324/soapService.asmx/displayClasses. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:17182' is therefore not allowed access.
```

```
EDIT Two :
complete code : Still Error.. msg not defined
<pre>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#findClassBtn").click(function () {

displayClass();
});

function onSuccess(msg) {
$.each(msg, function(i, item) {
var tds = "";
$.each(item, function(i, item) {
tds += "<td>" + item + "</td>";
});
$('#table').append("<tr>" + tds + "</tr>");
});
}

function displayClass() {
var instructorInputID = $('#instructorIdText').val();
var instructorInputDate = $('#instructordateText').val();
//send this id to web service
$.ajax({
url: "soapService.asmx/displayClasses",
type: "POST",
dataType:"json",
data: {
'id': instructorInputID,
'theDate': instructorInputDate
},
contentType: "application/json; charset:utf-8",
success: onSuccess(msg)
});
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
</div>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Add Your Id"></asp:Label>
<p>
<asp:TextBox ID="instructorIdText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Add date (dd/mm/yyyy)"></asp:Label>
<p>
<asp:TextBox ID="instructordateText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<asp:Button ID="findClassBtn" runat="server" OnClick="findClassBtn_Click" Text="Find Classes" />
<p>
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</p>
</form>
<table id="table">
</table>
<pre>

Error: msg is not defined.
```

Comment: In _data_ you tried to post the string, not the json object

Comment: I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function displayClass() {
        var instructorInputID = $('#instructorIdText').val();
        var instructorInputDate = $('#instructordateText').val();
        //send this id to web service

        $.ajax({

            url: "http://localhost/soapService.asmx/displayClasses",
            type: POST,
            dataType:"json",
            data: {
              'id': instructorInputID,
              'theDate': instructorInputDate
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset:utf-8",

            success: function (msg) {
              $.each(msg, function(i, item) {
                var tds = "";
                $.each(item, function(i, item) {
                  tds += "<td>" + item + "</td>";
                });
                $('#table').append("<tr>" + tds + "</tr>");
              });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
</table>
```

Comment: Added the code. It gives internal 500 error. The location of the webservice ASPX is on localhost and the client code is also on localhost. is this causing the problem??

Comment: @NurulAlamAnik This error? `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:18324/soapService.asmx/displayClasses. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:17182' is therefore not allowed access`

Comment: @ It seems you're trying to send request from `'http://localhost:17182'` to `http://localhost:18324/...`. It's cross-origin request. Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource.

Comment: Hi Romario...Now only error seems to be 
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 

I am returning json.. I think each only works with object.. I am not good with javascript.. I cant be sure.. can you kindly help on that?

Comment: @NurulAlamAnik It's better to accept this answer if it helped you and create new question with details of your problem.